# edit function creates a new user, and wont update the current user in the database

Tags: php, cakephp, sql-update, edit

I'm currently using CAKEPHP 2.3 and I'm trying to edit the user's information. but when I submit the information, it does not update the information in to the database. it instead creates a new user with the new information i inserted. i want it to update the user, not create a new one.

My code for the edit.ctp is:

```
    <h1>Edit Account information</h1>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'edit'));
echo $this->Form->input('username', array('value' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.username')));
echo $this->Form->input('name', array('value' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.name')));
echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
?>
```

And then my edit function in the users controller is:

```
public function edit() {
//        debug($this->User->save($this->request->data));
        $this->User->id = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
        $this->request->data['User']['id'];
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The User has been saved', true));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The User could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
            }
        } else {
            $this->request->data = $this->User->read(null);
            isset($this->request->data['User']['password']);
        }
    }
```

Here is the index to get to the edit user page.

```
<h1>Users Home</h1>
<p>Welcome <?php print $this->Session->read('Auth.User.name');?> <br/></p>
<table border="0" width="200" text-align="center">
<tr>
<td width="50"><?php echo $this->Html->link('Log out', array('action' => 'logout')); ?></td>
<td width="50"><?php echo $this->Html->link('Edit', array('action' => 'edit')); ?></td>
<td width="50"><?php echo $this->Html->link('Add User', array('action' => 'add')); ?></td><!-- should only show for admin -->
<td width="50"><?php echo $this->html->link('Manage Users', array('action' => 'usermanage')); ?></td><!-- should only show for admin -->
</tr>
</table>
```

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the `$id` of the User you want to edit. In this case, as only one user can edit his own profile, we do it at the controller:

```
public function edit() {
    $this->User->id = this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
    //whatever...
}
```

If you are on the edit view and the $id is passed by param, you don't even need to do it, just create the form like this and CakePHP will automatically generate the form for the edit action:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User');
```

Also, your inputs seems to be wrong, you don't need the `options` variable:

```
echo $this->Form->input('username', array('value' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.username')));
echo $this->Form->input('name', array('value' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.name')));
```

Comment: I have now specified the $id, but unfortunately it didn't work, it still pretends to update the users information, but doesn't really.:/

Comment: I updated my answer. It seems your inputs are not well created.

Comment: It still appears to do the same, could it have something to do with my controller?

Comment: What error do you get? Does it enters in the save condition or not? Can you also paste the generated HTMl of your form?

Comment: It doesn't show any error, it just wont update the database. it even tells me that the user has been updated..  

the generated html is in the question at the top, thanks for all your help

Comment: I have updated my answer. You were not taking the `$id` variable from anywhere. (your form was not sending it either). As @mark say, this should be done at the controller in a better way.

Comment: I have updated my code in the question, just to stay on track, but i am still getting the same problem. The database isn't being updated on submit.

Comment: Print the content of `$this->request->data` just before saving it and tell us what it contains.

Comment: 'array(
 'User' => array(
  'username' => 'iwanjones',
  'name' => 'Iwan'
 )
)'

Comment: under $this->User->id = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id') write $this->request->data['User']['id']; does it works ?

Comment: Hello Guignol, it has given this following error: 2Undefined index:  User [APP/Controller/UsersController.php, line 56"

Comment: Then you are giving us contradictory information. If you printed `$this->request->data` and it contains what you say, it can not throw you that error because `User` is an existence index...

Comment: @steve, i dont think i have been giving any contradictory information. Just to be sure i have now posted an updated version of the Controller and the View and added the index page before the edit page (noticed that some users post that as well).

Answer (score 1):

lose the $id in your edit method. usually a user can only - and only himself - edit his own record.

```
public function edit() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->request->data['User']['id'] = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
        ...
```

and `value` is wrong for your forms. never use that. it breaks your form on post and validation errors (see http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/23/working-with-forms/ for the "why" - you will also find how you can set default values if you really need to).

since you pass down data via `$this->request->data` you need to leave them as they were:

```
echo $this->Form->input('username');
```

also lose the action. the form will automatically post to itself!

last but not least dont use read(), use find(first)

Answer (score 0):

You can also include it in the form. By default, the id field will be hidden in the form. Doing it with session is more secure but you can do it this way for admin functions or verify it before a save.

```
 echo $this->Form->input('User.id');
```